# Why women dont have their right to get married herself

Tags: nikah, women

From some websites, I have learned that women cannot get married by themselves and she must need the permission of their wali in marriage. Here, in a condition, her son will be her wali. So it can be seen that if a woman wants to marry on her own, she will need the permission of her own child. The son or any wali can annul her marrige

Do woman don't have the right of marrige?

Comment: How can she have a son before marrying ?

Comment: @An_Elephant after divorce